# Office Add-in development: Connect to SharePoint site and get data

Tags: javascript, office-addins, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I would like to ask how would I make my Office add-in connect to SharePoint? I need to get all the document name uploaded in there and have it download the selected file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access files stored in SharePoint and OneDrive via the Microsoft Graph. You can find information about this here - https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/